# XQuery: Delete specific parent node based on child value

Tags: sql, xquery, xquery-sql

I'm trying to delete a parent node from an xml document based on the value of a child node

Here's a really simplified example of what I'm looking at

```
<root>
  <someactivity>
    <id>123456789</id>
  </someactivity>
</root>
```

What I'd like to be able to do using SQL Server / XQuery is to delete the entire 'someactivity' node and its contents by searching for the id of '123456789' in the child node 'id'.

So far I've got something like this:-

```
update mytablecontainingXMLcolumns
  set xmldata.modify('delete //someactivity/id[text()][contains(.,"123456789")]')
```

but it's not working as I expected - only seems to be deleting the 'id' node.  I'm stuck at this stage.  Any help / guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your XPath/XQuery to be selecting the parent `someactivity` element instead of `id` :

```
update mytablecontainingXMLcolumns
  set xmldata.modify('delete //someactivity[contains(id,"123456789")]')
```

or, if there can be multiple `id` elements within one `someactivity` and you want to delete the parent if, at least, one `id` matched :

```
update mytablecontainingXMLcolumns
  set xmldata.modify('delete //someactivity[id[contains(.,"123456789")]]')
```